# Angularjs $http.get does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angularjs-http

My purpose is to consume a REST web service in AngularJS and I am making some trials right now. Below code is not working and throwing following exception. 
Can you help me identifty the problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
function getUsersFromLocal($scope,$http)
{
 $http.get('http://localhost:8080/people').
 success(function(data) {
 $scope.data = data;
 });
return data;
}
```

Error is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at getUsersFromLocal.

The service is accessible and I tested it through some REST clients.

Comment: Is `getUsersFromLocal()` a controller?

Comment: You need to supply more context. Where is `getUsersFromLocal()` defined? The ultimate problem is that Angular's `$injector` service doesn't know to do dependency injection on the call to `getUsersFromLocal()` (wherever that is in your code). Follow either @zegoline's answer or @pankajparkar's answer to address your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly `getUsersFromLocal` function is inside controller, basically the function parameters are killing the `$scope`, `$http` object existence, You need to remove them from parameter & Also removed the return statement which was outside `$http` which won't work in anyways.

**Code**

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
    $scope.getUsersFromLocal = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/people').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.getUsersFromLocal(); //call ajax method
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I could choose only one correct answer. I also marked other comments as okay.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this , this way i found on w3school.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp4', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
                .success(function(response) {
                    $scope.data= response.records;
                });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

if `getUsersFromLocal` is not a controller or service, and you are invoking this function manually, you should pass `$http` and `$scope` objects to it, like this

```
module.controller('TestController', function($scope, $http) {

  function getUsersFromLocal($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/people').
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
      });
  }

  getUsersFromLocal($scope, $http); // pass this services manually
});
```